# MApping through objects in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to map over an array of objects and need only the name vale of the first object. I tried to chain `detail.name[0]` and it gives the first value of every object.

```
  var arrayColor = [
    {id: 1, name:[[1,2]]},
    {id: 2, name:[[3,4],[4,6]]},
    {id: 3, name:[[4,5,2],[2,4,5]]}
  ]



arrayColor.map((detail, i) =>
 console.log(detail.name[0]) // need only `name:[[1,2]]`
 console.log(detail[0].name) `error: cannot read property name of undefined`
)
```

Comment: `arrayColor.map(...)` will give a new array - which you then don't do anything with. If you just want the `[[1,2]]` there is no need to map anything - just `console.log(arrayColor[0].name);`

Comment: I feel stupid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

answer here is simple. the reason the second read is giving you an error, is because detail is a single value within the array, and not the array itself.

solution: use the original array as reference. 
here is the code:

```
arrayColor.map((detail) => {id:detail.id, name:arrayColor[0].name})
```